# using datatable with amCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am migrating google charts to amCharts. I am using a data array like this:

```
[ 
  [CITY, SUM],
  [A,    1500],
  [B,    1470],
  [C,    1920]
]
```

I can use this in google charts. So this solution is very flexible and dynamic. And I do not set any value field ot category field like amCharts.

But I see that amCharts data should be json object array.

```
[ 
  {CITY: A,   SUM: 1500},
  {CITY: B,   SUM: 1470},
  {CITY: C,   SUM: 1920}
]
```

So I need to know `value` ad `category` propery for every dataset.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "categoryField": "CITY",
  "graphs": [{
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "SUM"
  }]
}
```

SO this is not very flexible.

Is there any solution to get;

- first item of json object is categoryField
- second item of solution is valueField

Or using google datatable data in amCharts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is not available out of the box as AmCharts requires this information to be defined upfront.

You can certainly write a pre-processing method or a plugin through AmCharts' [`addInitHandler`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCharts#addInitHandler) method to convert your data and create graphs for you. Here's a basic example which defines a custom `dataTable` property containing the settings needed to make a custom plugin work:

```
//mini plugin to handle google datatable array of arrays format
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {
  if (!chart.dataTable && !chart.dataTable.data && !chart.dataTable.graph) {
    return;
  }  
  var dataProvider;
  var graphs = [];
  var graphTemplate = chart.dataTable.graph;
  var fields = chart.dataTable.data[0];
  var data = chart.dataTable.data.slice(1);

  fields.slice(1).forEach(function(valueField) {
    graphs.push({
      type: graphTemplate.type || "line",
      fillAlphas: graphTemplate.fillAlphas || 0,
      lineAlpha: graphTemplate.lineAlpha || 1,
      valueField: valueField
    });
  });

  dataProvider = data.map(function(arr) {
    var dataObj = {};
    arr.forEach(function(value, idx) {
      dataObj[fields[idx]] = value;
    })
    return dataObj;
  });

  chart.categoryField = fields[0];
  chart.graphs = graphs;
  chart.dataProvider = dataProvider; 
});

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light", 
  //custom dataTable property used by the chart to accept dataTable format
  "dataTable": {  
    "data": dataTable,
    "graph": { //graph template for all value fields
      "type": "column",
      "fillAlphas": .8,
      "lineAlpha": 1
    }
  }
});
```

You can extend this as much as you need.

Here's a demo using your data and an additional column of dummy data:

```js
var dataTable = [
  ["CITY", "SUM", "AVG"],
  ["A", 1500, 500],
  ["B", 1470, 490],
  ["C", 1920, 640]
];

//mini plugin to handle google datatable array of arrays format
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {
  //check if the required properties for the plugin are defined before proceeding
  if (!chart.dataTable && !chart.dataTable.data && !chart.dataTable.graph) {
    return;
  }
  var dataProvider;
  var graphs = [];
  var graphTemplate = chart.dataTable.graph;
  var fields = chart.dataTable.data[0];
  var data = chart.dataTable.data.slice(1);

  //create the graph objects using the graph template from the custom dataTable property
  fields.slice(1).forEach(function(valueField) {
    graphs.push({
      type: graphTemplate.type || "line",
      fillAlphas: graphTemplate.fillAlphas || 0,
      lineAlpha: graphTemplate.lineAlpha || 1,
      valueField: valueField
    });
  });

  //construct the dataProvider array from the datatable data
  dataProvider = data.map(function(arr) {
    var dataObj = {};
    arr.forEach(function(value, idx) {
      dataObj[fields[idx]] = value;
    })
    return dataObj;
  });

  //update the chart properties
  chart.categoryField = fields[0];
  chart.graphs = graphs;
  chart.dataProvider = dataProvider;
});

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  //custom dataTable property used by the chart to accept dataTable format
  "dataTable": {
    "data": dataTable,
    "graph": { //graph template for all value fields
      "type": "column",
      "fillAlphas": .8,
      "lineAlpha": 1
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```